# Can Zeroconfig names be used to specify a nfs server address

Tags: networking, routing, nas

The powers that be have decided that machines that can access sites beyond the firewall must use DHCP.

I have a (Netgear ReadyNAS) NAS server that is on the same subnet as a cluster and I would like the cluster to access the NAS using NFS. The NAS broadcasts its address via Zeroconfig (mDNS) to the subnet and Macintoshes and Windows machines have no problem see it.

Is there a way to get the server to utilize this information as a NFS volume? This would be the preferred solution as the permissions problems can be handled by settings on the NAS. A second option would be to use `mount_cifs`, but I am not sure how to handle the permissions issue.

Does anyone have any useful advice?

Comment: DHCP doesn't mean the address will change daily (especially for a device that's always online it probably won't change for years). Have you tried asking the powers that be about a static DHCP lease for your NAS?

Answer (score 0):

ZeroConf names can be used to specify an NFS server address if your NFS client software calls DNS/networking APIs that give your system's mDNS resolver a chance to answer. So the answer is most likely "Yes" on macOS, and "hard to say" on Linux and Windows.

There's no way to know what your NFS client software does on your platform unless you try it.

Answer (score 0):

It also works on Linux (openSUSE Tumbleweed here), given that you open your machine's firewall for zeroconf/mdns.

However, mounting at boot (via `/etc/fstab`) might create a timing problem as zeroconf might not be properly initialised when the directories are mounted.